# PIG: FLATTEN error

Tags: apache-pig, flatten

I have a relation `X` with structure  `X: {group: chararray,inboundCount: {(name: chararray,inb: long)},outboundCount: {(name: chararray,out: long)}}`as follows:

```
(IAD,{},{(IAD,25)})
(LAX,{},{(LAX,2)})
(ORD,{(ORD,27)},{})
(PDX,{},{(PDX,3)}) 
(SFO,{(SFO,3)},{})
```

I want an output with the following structure `final: {airport: chararray,inbound: long,outbound: long}`with out put:

```
(IAD,,25)
(LAX,,2)
(ORD,27,)
(PDX,,3)
(SFO,3,)
```

I've tried the following code and it gives the output structure that I want. But nothing get printed. Is it because of the null value bags?.

```
final = foreach X generate group as airport,FLATTEN(inboundCount.inb) as inbound,FLATTEN(outboundCount.out) as outbound;
```

Please help me.

**EDIT**
I got this relation `x` by executing the following commands.

```
A= load '/user/hduser/airline.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (year:int,month:int,dayofmonth:int,dayofweek:int,dep:int,CRS:int,Arr:int,CRSArr:int,UniqueCarrier:chararray,FlightNum:int,TailNum:chararray,ActualElapsedTime:int,CRSElapsed:int,AirTime:int,ArrDelay:int,DepDelay:int,Origin:chararray,Dest:chararray,Distance:int,TaxiIn:int,TaxiOut:int,Cancelled:int,CancelCode:chararray,Diverted:int,CarrierDelay:int,WeatherDelay:int,NASDelay:int,SecurityDelay:int,LateAircraft:int);
B= foreach A generate year,month,UniqueCarrier,FlightNum,TailNum,Origin,Dest;
inbound = group B by Dest;
inboundCount = foreach inbound generate group,COUNT(B.FlightNum) as inb;
outbound = group B by Origin;
outboundCount = foreach outbound generate group,COUNT(B.FlightNum) as out;
X = COGROUP inboundCount BY name, outboundCount BY name;
```

Sample input record:

> 2008,1,31,4,1757,1155,2400,1758,UA,114,N845UA,243,243,217,362,362,LAX,ORD,1745,11,15,0,,0,0,0,362,0,0

Comment: Ok. This is just relation X. Could you give the real  input dataset and the respective pig statement you have written to reach that relation X

Comment: @SurenderRaja I have edited the question. Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok. It looks like you would like to find how many flights took off  from and landed in  in each airport.Is that correct?

Comment: @SurenderRaja Yes. Exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.Pls try this .just apply SUM instead of flatten

```
 A= load '/user/hduser/airline.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (year:int,month:int,dayofmonth:int,dayofweek:int,dep:int,CRS:int,Arr:int,CRSArr:int,UniqueCarrier:chararray,FlightNum:int,TailNum:chararray,ActualElapsedTime:int,CRSElapsed:int,AirTime:int,ArrDelay:int,DepDelay:int,Origin:chararray,Dest:chararray,Distance:int,TaxiIn:int,TaxiOut:int,Cancelled:int,CancelCode:chararray,Diverted:int,CarrierDelay:int,WeatherDelay:int,NASDelay:int,SecurityDelay:int,LateAircraft:int);

B= foreach A generate year,month,UniqueCarrier,FlightNum,TailNum,Origin,Dest;

inbound = group B by Dest;

inboundCount = foreach inbound generate group,COUNT(B.FlightNum) as inb;

outbound = group B by Origin;

outboundCount = foreach outbound generate group,COUNT(B.FlightNum) as out;

X = COGROUP inboundCount BY name, outboundCount BY name;

final_data = FOREACH X GENERATE group as airport, SUM(inboundCount.inb) as inb, SUM(outboundCount.out) as out;

dump final_data;
```

The dump of final_data will give you the expected result.

```
(IAD,,25)
(LAX,,2)
(ORD,27,)
(PDX,,3)
(SFO,3,)
```

If you want then you can still replace the NULL count into 0

```
 final_null_check = FOREACH final_data GENERATE airport,(inb is null ? 0 :inb) as inb_cnt, (out is null ? 0 : out) as out_cnt;
```

After NULL Check if you dump final_null_check relation the you will get output like below

```
 (IAD,0,25)
 (LAX,0,2)
 (ORD,27,0)
 (PDX,0,3)
 (SFO,3,0)
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked very well. But can you tell me why it didn't work using FLATTEN?